# IFTTT webhook to google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, integration, webhooks, ifttt

I am sending a request to a IFTTT webhook, which receives the request and saves it to a google sheets file.

There are a few predefined available fields that I can use to send to IFTTT, which in turn get passed forward to the google sheets file (Value1, Value2, Value3).

When sending the request to IFTTT, I can pass those fields in the JSON object I am sending, like this:

```
{
"value1": article.title,
"value2": article.summary,
"value3": article.text,
}
```

The problem arises if I wish to send another value. Imagine I want to add an "image" field. I can update the JSON to be sent to:

```
{
"value1": article.title,
"value2": article.summary,
"value3": article.text,
"image": article.image
}
```

but within IFTTT, if I try to add that field in the action to send it to google, I can save the applet (even though the field shows up in red) but nothing gets passed to the google sheets file in that field (the other 3 fields are still being sent).

[image]

Where and how can I add the extra field? Do I need to change something in the webhook, do something in the filter, or how can I pass other, custom fields?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done the way I was looking to do it.

You cannot add custom fields to the webhook.

What I ended up doing was sending all of the fields I needed inside `VALUE1` as JSON, and forward that to another service to be processed.

Hell of a hack, but seems like an IFTTT limitation. In the meanwhile I have migrated to Zapier, and it's a whole different world!